# Is it possible to get the destination sheet from app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to identify the destination sheet for a google form.   I can get the spreadsheet using:

```
function getDataSheet(){
 var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
 var id = form.getDestinationId();
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);

 var sheet = "";  // how do I get the sheet that the data will go to? 
}
```

The problem is how can I get the sheet that the form results will go to?  I can guess that it is [0], but that is not a guarantee.

Comment: I found this issue, related to what I am trying to do: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5448&q=form%20destination%20sheet&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Answer (score 2):

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var formId = form.getId();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for(i=0; i<sheets.length; i++){
  var sheetFormURL = sheets[i].getFormUrl();
  if(sheetFormURL) {
    if(sheetFormURL.indexOf(formId)!=-1) {
      var sheet = sheets[i];
      break;
    }        
  }
}
  
if(typeof sheet !== 'undefined'){
  //do what you need to do in the sheet
}
```

Comment: although good answers usually carry the code explanation and documentation links, this answer, even without them, is the only one that does the job in a clean and straight manner.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no "built-in" way to get the sheet tab of the Form destination.

If the user of the spreadsheet has not changed the default sheet name given, then you can loop through all the sheets, get the sheet name, and check for a name that includes the text: "Form Responses".

The first default name given is:

> Form Responses 1

Then, if more destinations are added, the number at the end is increased.

If the user changes the name, then obviously, you can *not* use that strategy.  If you can get the sheet tab name as soon as the new destination is created, then store the sheet tab ID in the documents properties, that would ensure that you have the information available.   Having the sheet tab ID is better than having the sheet tab destination name, that way, if the destination sheet tab name gets changed, you can still find the correct sheet tab by looking the ID up from the document properties, then using the ID to get the sheet tab.

If the spreadsheet has multiple Form Responses X sheets, and you wanted to get the last destination added, you would need to get the number off the end, and find out what the highest number is.

There should be a way to get the destination sheet tab.  I don't know if there is a feature request for that or not.

Comment: My current problem is that this functionality is part of an international add-on, and Form Responses 1 is only the default for English.    I wonder if there is a way to figure out the destination sheet.  Like if timestamp is in Cell A1.

Comment: Good point.  I'd probably want to check more than one cell.  I'd check A2:A4 and make sure there was a time stamp in all 3 cells, just to make sure.  If the data ended in A2 or A3, then you'd need to just go with that, and hope for the best.  If you wanted to be 100% sure, you might need to have the code add a sheet tab, then store the sheet tab ID, then write the responses from code instead of the Form doing that automatically.   But, if you do it that way, then you run into problems with data getting written to the wrong row, or not written at all, if lots of users submit at the same time.

Comment: You could get the time stamp from cell A2, then compare that timestamp to the very first timestamp in the form.  Of course, that assumes that a form submission has already been made.  If no form submission has been made, then you'd need to submit a response from code, then do the test.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing as a workaround.   It will try and find the datasheet, and should work for most forms.   It is not very efficient, but should hopefully work to get most forms.

```
 function getDestinationSheet(ss){
  if(!ss){
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var id = form.getDestinationId();
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  }
  var possibleDS = [];
  var allSheetNames =[];
  var dsName = {};


  var locale = ss.getSpreadsheetLocale();
  var text = "Timestamp";
  if(locale != "en_US"){
  text = LanguageApp.translate(text, "en_US", locale);
  }

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(i in sheets){
    var s = sheets[i];
    var sName = s.getName();
    allSheetNames.push(sName);
    var a1 = s.getRange("A1").getValue();
    if (a1 == text){ possibleDS.push(sName) }
  }

  var l = possibleDS.length;
  switch (l){
    case 0:
      dsName.name = "Error";
      dsName.error = "No matches found"; 
      dsName.sheets = allSheetNames; 
      break;

    case 1:
      dsName.name = possibleDS[0];
      dsName.error = "Sucess"; 
      break;

    default:
      dsName.name = "Error";
      dsName.error = "Unable to determine destination sheet using timestamp"; 
      dsName.sheets = possibleDS; 
      break;
  }

return dsName;
}
```